# Enable Constraint - Peformance Impact

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ddl, database-administration

The below statement consumes a huge amount of time for a table containing 70 million records.

```
ALTER TABLE <table-name>  ENABLE CONSTRAINT <constraint-name>
```

Does table scan all rows while enabling the constraint.

Even though the constraint got enabled, the process just hung for more than 5 hours.

Any ideas on how this can be optimized

Comment: *"Does table scan all rows while enabling the constraint?"* Yes.

Comment: As for optimising it, there probably aren't that many options. Some details would be useful. What sort of constraint is it? Why was it disabled? What happened while it was disabled?

Comment: Depends on how the constrains was disabled, see [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general005.htm#ADMIN11546). But usually - YES - enabling the constraint causes scanning of all rows in order to validate the constraint.

Comment: @APC- it is a part of an existing stored procedure that we can enable this constraint .. It was disabled in order  to update test data on some columns.. Post that it was enabled again.. But this step got hung and it took a huge amount of time

Comment: But what sort of constraint was it? Check constraint? Primary key? Foreign key? And what is the perceived benefit of disabling the constraint before the update compared to doing the update with it enabled?

Answer (score 4):

As guys said before, depends on constrain type it is possibility skip validate existing data by ALTER TABLE  ENABLE NOVALIDATE CONSTRAINT . And check this data by some additional procedure or query.

You can find documentation about that here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general005.htm#ADMIN11546